# Why is my Python Django home url not working?

Tags: python, django, web

my first url in django is not working. Not sure what I am doing. My directories are as follows:

Storefront

- playground

  - urls.py
  - views.py
- storefront

  - urls.py

playground.urls

```
from nturl2path import url2pathname
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('hello/', views.hello)
]
```

playground.views

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello World')
```

storefront.urls

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('playground/', include('playground.urls'))
]
```

When I go to the website/playground/url, I get an error saying the urls wasn't found. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The path is `/playground/hello/`.

Comment: Yea it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Sorry I realized what I wrote before was incorrect because I answered it in a rush.

I used the exact code you put in the question and was unable to reproduce the error.

Make sure you are going to the following web address:

> 127.0.0.1:8000/playground/hello

The reason this is the address is because in storefront.urls you are specifying that the root of the storefront app is the "playground/" route and the only route in the playground app is "hello/".

If you want to go to the following and have it show the "hello" view like this:

> 127.0.0.1:8000/playground/

You will need to change:

```
path('hello/', views.hello)
```

to this instead:

```
path('', views.hello)
```

If you are looking for a good tutorial on Django, Codemy.com has a free playlist on YouTube. John goes through step by step to build a full blog website. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLCC34OHNcOtr025c1kHSPrnP18YPB-NFi

Comment: Still not working